# How to fix: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, django, utf-8, ethereum, encode

I have recently started programming.
I am trying to simulate an ethereum transaction with the help of Ropsten.
When I try to run the function (sendTransaction ("message")) with the Django's shell I get this error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.
The full errors track is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\bakeka\bloggo\utils.py", line 18, in sendTransaction
    tx = w3.eth.sendTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\bakeka\globale\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 577, in send_transaction
    return self._send_transaction(transaction)
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\bakeka\globale\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 53, in caller
    (method_str, params), response_formatters = method.process_params(module, *args, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\bakeka\globale\lib\site-packages\web3\method.py", line 179, in process_params
    params = self.input_munger(module, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\bakeka\globale\lib\site-packages\web3\method.py", line 168, in input_munger
    root_munger(module, *args, **kwargs),
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\bakeka\globale\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 120, in send_transaction_munger
    if 'from' not in transaction and is_checksum_address(self.default_account):
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

(Francesco is my username, bakeka is my project, globale is my venv)

```
from web3 import Web3

def sendTransaction(message):
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('My Ropsten Ip'))
    address = 'my addres'
    privateKey = 'my private key'
    nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)
    gasPrice = w3.eth.gasPrice
    value = w3.toWei(0, 'ether')
    signedTx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(dict(
        nonce = nonce,
        gasPrice = gasPrice,
        gas = 10000,
        to = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        value = value,
        data = message.encode('utf-8'),
    ), privateKey)
    tx = w3.eth.sendTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
    txId = w3.toHex(tx)
    return txId
```

Can you help me? Thank u all!!

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation for `w3.eth.sendTransaction`? In particular, what does it say should be the *type* of the data you pass? What is the type of `signedTx.rawTransaction`? Does that match? (Hint: what do you think the"raw" in `rawTransaction` is intended to mean?) Now, what happened when you looked at the rest of the interface for `signedTx`? Do you see anything that gives you the appropriate thing to pass to `w3.eth.sendTransaction`?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.